# getting the values from searchbox upon user entry in visualSearchjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-autocomplete

Ive been working with the `visualSearch.js` plugin for `autocomplete`. It is developed using `backbone.js` ,

I will add a wrking model to show where Ive reached and what Im trying to achieve. http://jsfiddle.net/HRuAP/50/ To explain,

I am trying to add facet search option and wants to get the value of alphabets that are being typed by the user for  facet matching.

I have tried to get the characters typed using `$(".ui-autocomplete-input").val()`  it returns the characters typed for the first trial, when we try to enter the second facet, it returns empty string. we can view the `console.log` value using `firebug`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the characters using the `keydown` event:

```
var input = '';
$('body').keydown(function(event) {
    if(event.keyCode == 8){
        input = input.slice(0,-1);
    }else{
        input += String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);
    }
    console.log(input, input.split(' '));
});​
```

The only problem is that this seems to return only uppercase characters.

Comment: uppercase is nt an issue, bt i want them as separate words.. because im trying to send an ajax post request with the keys entered..

Comment: Updated the code a little. This won't work properly if a user clicks on one of the suggestions, but it does catch the keyboard events.

Comment: Don't place that code in the callback, just put it at the end of your script, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/HRuAP/53/

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? What does it do that it shouldn't?

Comment: sometimes the words could be two or three letter word.. so it doesnt make sense splitting words based on spaces.. it wil capture events like enter and backspaces wont remove the letters..as im trying to use these values to send post requests..

Comment: Backspaces are in fact taken care of in `if(event.keyCode == 8)` For the rest, I can't really help any further, I'm afraid.